# SCSS Compiler Extension for Visual Studio

Tags: css, visual-studio, sass, web-compiler, mindscape

I would like to compile SCSS into CSS in my Visual Studio Community 2015 and 2017 projects.

The extensions I have come across are:

- Web Compiler (1 million downloads)
- Mindscape Web Workbench (282k downloads) just VS 2015
- Sam Rueby's CompileSass

The products seem very similar and both seem to have trouble with some SASS features.

Is there a particularly strong reason that I should opt for one extension over the other?